# Do calls to shmget or shmat initialize data?

Tags: c, memory, shared

When using shared memory in c, is it possible to first create data and then attach it to the shared segment (something like initialization)? Or must I first create the shared segment and then attach data to it?

I do think that both ways are correct, but I am not sure of what is exactly happening during calls to `shmget` and `shmat`. Do any of these calls, initialize the attached data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to first create data and then attach it to the shared segment?

No.

> Or must I first create the shared segment and then attach data to it?

Yes - you get the piece of memory, then you write/place data in it.

shmat() gives you a pointer to the shared segment. When you assign that to an existing pointer in your program, that pointer points to this piece of memory.

> Do any of these calls, initialize the attached data?

When creating a new shared memory segment, all bytes within it will be initialized to zero. When attaching a segment that already is created, you get whatever you placed in that segment previously.